# Add restrictions for files and folders naming on Windows

Tags: windows, ntfs, restrictions

Is it possible, with Windows Seven pro, to add restrictions on the naming for files and folders?

Let me explain:

My users can't refrain from using characters like `é`, `ô`, or string like `l'agence ++`.

They also call their files with very long strings, like 30 or 40 characters!

This cause me a lot of troubles, and I lost a lot of time fixing names due to encoding problems with some software, or worth, impossibility to delete or rename files because the [NTFS Maximum Path Length Limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) of 260 charaters has been exceeded!

I would like to permit only:

- Alphanumeric characters, without diacritics `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- dot (`.`), minus (`-`) and underscore (`_`)
- limit files and folders naming to 10 or 12 characters
- **no spaces**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 has no features like that, but Windows 2008R2 has some. You can use File Screening to prevent any user to create certain file patterns on a disk. This will also work with users on a client PC that will create files on a Windows 2008R2 File share.

You can access the settings in *File server resource manager* (if installed).

I don't recommend setting the rules too tight though.

Comment: How does this affect the existing files?

Comment: Existing files will be untouched. They can still be opened.

Comment: Hum, I tried it, it is very poor… I just can use `*` for wildcard, and I have to list ALL of the characters prohibited, one by one, like `é`, `*é`, `é*`, `*é*`… Worst of all, the error message for the user is not relevant, like "You do not have the right to access this file, contact your SysAdmin…". Maybe I misunderstood how it work? I untag my question as `answered ` for now, maybe there is other solutions?

Comment: It certainly will not address ALL your wishes, but I don't think any Windows functionality will. Maybe you better look for 3d party tools.

Comment: Do you have some example im mind?